# How long do objects stay in memory after a soap request to WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, garbage-collection

I was wondering how long do objects instantiated during a soap request ( which do not implement IDisposable ) stay in memory?

for example:

```
...
public GetRecordsResponse GetRecords(GetRecordsRequest request)
    {
        GetRecordsTransaction transaction = new GetRecordsTransaction();
        GetRecordsResponse response = transaction.GetResponse(request);
        return response;
    }
...
```

**How long would the transaction stay in memory?**

As soon as soap sends the response? session (if that exists in wcf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing IDisposable has little to do with managed memory.  Garbage collection is about cleaning up managed memory; but IDisposable is intended to allow control of releasing unmanaged resources.

From your code sample, you have no guarantee of how long your objects are in memory for, and you should definitely not make any assumptions about how soon (or late) the garbage collector will reclaim the memory for those objects once they are no longer referenced by your code.

May I ask why you need to know?  It sounds as though you are expecting your transactions to have some sort of behaviour at the point of garbage collection, when what you really want is to explicitly rollback or commit them.  If you could explain your root problem, that might help clarify the question.

Comment: Well, i don't know if i have a problem yet. I was just wondering to try to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 2):

They are not cached. They may happen not to be garbage collected for a while.

Comment: okay, yeah, i'm looking to find out how long that "while" is.

Comment: It's arbitrary. They will remain for as long as the garbage collector wants them to, and just a little longer than _you_ want them to.

Comment: And this is why folks implement `IDisposable`: so you have control over the object lifetime.

Comment: Unless folks have gross misconceptions regarding `IDisposable` (which, given the track record of other features such as GC and value types, isn't that unlikely): No, folks implement `IDisposable` to get rid of unmanaged resources. Disposing doesn't deallocate objects.